# Looking for the name of a top bar notification provider

Tags: notification

Not long ago I saw a website that had a top notification bar that was provided by a third party, customizable and all by I can't for the life of me remember what those guys were called. I'm looking for something similar to what the "Stack" website have (including this one) when visiting the first time. Just a simple bar that can be dismissed or slit closed.

Any answers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://tympanus.net/Development/jbar/

Comment: Not exactly the one I remember seeing, since it did say in a corner "powered by *something*" but thanks, this should do the trick.

Comment: @Tux, no worries, it seems to look and work nicely, I don't think you'll go wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

I have used both of these and they are fairly decent in terms of customization..

http://www.tutorialshock.com/tutorials/social-floating-bar-jquery-javascript/

http://www.bitsntuts.com/css/pretty-css3-jquery-top-bar-navigation